# Click on a textbox selects all data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, search

Clicking on a text box selects all data. My present code selects in all textbox. But i want to apply it in a specific box.
Present code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus(function() { 
       $(this).select(); 
    });
});
```

I want to apply it on search box only.
code for search box is following:

```
<input name="q" id="searchBox" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  #id selector.Like this...

```
$("#searchBox").focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: did you put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... } );` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchBox").focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

Comment: i am using it, but this is not my requirement.